# Shopware 6 add entity extension fields to admin search

Tags: api, shopware, shopware6

I wonder how to make some fields of an entity extension searchable in the administration through the "/api/search/my-entity" api-endpoint. By default they are not considered during search as it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by debugging the search-endpoint:
The association-Field of the EntityExtension needs to have a `SearchRanking`-flag:

```php
...->addFlags(new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::ASSOCIATION_SEARCH_RANKING))
```

Then you can add `SearchRanking`-flags in the EntityExtensionDefinition as you like, e.g.:

```php
(new StringField('test', 'test'))->addFlags(new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::HIGH_SEARCH_RANKING)),
```

After that the fields are searchable via the search-endpoint :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the API is concerned, search functionality should automatically be generated following your custom entity definitions.

When it comes to facilitate Admin search for your entity, you need to add some code to the administration component as described in the docs: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/search-custom-data (even though it looks not fully up-to-date w.r.t to the current Shopware versions).

Comment: Thanks, for the API this seems to work for custom entities, but not for entity extensions of existing entities...
Regarding the second point: maybe I misphrased this a bit, I don't want to add this to the global admin search, but rather to the search in the entity-listing, which uses the default search-api endpoint.